# VTK Plane through 3D points

Tags: vector, vtk, plane

I have a set of 3D points and need to fit the best fitting plane which I am doing with the following code (found on stackoverflow):

```
points = np.reshape(points, (np.shape(points)[0], -1))
assert points.shape[0] <= points.shape[1], "There are only {} points in {} dimensions.".format(points.shape[1], points.shape[0])

ctr = points.mean(axis=1)
x = points - ctr[:, np.newaxis]
M = np.dot(x, x.T)
return ctr, svd(M)[0][:,-1] # return point and normal vector
```

Afterwards I want to display the plane in VTK. The problem is I have to scale the plane, but when I do so the plane is translated as well. How can I prevent that from happening ?

```
def create_vtk_plane_actor(point, normal_vector):
 print("\n Display plane with point: %s and vector: %s" % (point, normal_vector))

 plane_source = vtk.vtkPlaneSource()
 plane_source.SetOrigin(point[0], point[1], point[2])
 plane_source.SetNormal(normal_vector[0], normal_vector[1], normal_vector[2])
 plane_source.Update()

 transform = vtk.vtkTransform()
 transform.Scale(1.5, 1.5, 1.0)

 transform_filter = vtk.vtkTransformFilter()
 transform_filter.SetInputConnection(plane_source.GetOutputPort())
 transform_filter.SetTransform(transform)

 actor = vtk.vtkActor()

 mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
 mapper.SetInputConnection(transform_filter.GetOutputPort())
```

Answer (score 0):

The scale is not applied on some coordinates local to your plan but on those you set. So indeed, the center will move. If you want to let it, you need to set a `Translate` on your transform.

Answer (score 0):

Fitting planes is a builtin feature in [vtkplotter](https://github.com/marcomusy/vtkplotter), scaling is done with `mesh.scale()`:

```py
from vtkplotter import *
from vtkplotter import datadir
from vtkplotter.pyplot import histogram

plt = Plotter()

apple = load(datadir+"apple.ply").subdivide().addGaussNoise(1)
plt += apple.alpha(0.1)

variances = []
for i, p in enumerate(apple.points()):
    pts = apple.closestPoint(p, N=12) # find the N closest points to p
    plane = fitPlane(pts)             # find the fitting plane and scale
    variances.append(plane.variance)
    if i % 400: continue
    print(i, plane.variance)
    plt += plane.scale(2)
    plt += Points(pts)              
    plt += Arrow(plane.center, plane.center+plane.normal/10)

plt += histogram(variances).scale(6).pos(1.2,.2,-1)
plt.show()
```

[image]